# Map a link with a function

Tags: php

Suppose I have a link and a function as below, how can I map this link with the function?

As a result, user click on the link "remove user" will execute the function "remove_user

```
<a href="xxx">remove all compare items</a>

functio remove_user() {
return mysql_query("DELETE * FROM compre_items");
}
```

Comment: You do not want "remove user" to be a link because it will issue a GET request and [GET requests should be safe and idempotent](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html). Also, if spiders get access to that page, they will delete the user.

Comment: judging by the downvotes, you might want to clarify what the problem is.

Comment: ok, I updated my question, it should be deleting the items in the compare section

Comment: thanks, but that's not what I mean by clarifying the question. It's rather that it is unclear why you cannot simply point the href attribute to a php script that does the deletion. It is unclear what you need help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do something like this:

```
<a href="?action=delete">remove user</a>
<?php
    if ($_GET['action'] == 'delete') {
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM user WHERE id = 0");
    }
?>
```

But this is not good pattern/style to develop web applications.

Check out [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) to separate business and presentation logic. Than MVC frameworks like Zend Framework, Cake PHP or others.

Comment: just a note: better to use `switch` statement, than many `if/else`

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="?action=remove_user&id=1">

<?php
    switch($_GET['action']){
        case "remove_user":
            $id = intval($_GET['id']);
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM user WHERE id = {$id}");
        break;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but here is a simple suggestion:

```
<a href="functions.php?action=remove_user">remove user</a>
```

Create functions.php (or whatever you want to call it) and put your remove_user() function inside, then add this logic:

```
if ($_GET['action']=="remove_user") {
    remove_user();  
}
```

You'll probably want to add something that tells the function which user to remove though ...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use jQuery Ajax :

```
// --------- file.php 

functio remove_user() {
$result =  mysql_query("DELETE FROM user WHERE id = 0");
if( $result ) echo 1 ; else echo 0;
exit();
}

remove_user();
```

// --------- html File

```
    <a href="xxx" id="remove">remove user</a>
    <div id="result"></div>
    $('#remove').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "file.php",
                context:$(this)
                success:function ( data ){

                if( data == 1 )
                  $("#result").html('Remove Succesfully');
                else
                  $("#result").html('Faild To Remove');

                }
          });

)};
```